# how to query data from a postgres table ex 'pg_stat_statements' in Spring data?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Hello I am using a spring boot application and my requirement is to query pg_stat_statements table for some metrics. I am confused as I cant define a repository because this is not an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create view with this table, add row_number() as Id of this view, then create entity based on this view and use it in HQL